# Error when using suggest mode in a GitHub pull request (large file)

Tags: github

In our GitHub pull requests, we are using suggestion mode successfully when we edit smaller files, however, when we try to suggest a change in a large file (in this case a large ontology file), I get this error when I try to commit suggested changes: `This diff has recently been updated. Refresh and try again.` It does, however, not work when I refresh and try again (same message).

[image: screenshot of the error message]

Comment: Try to add the screenshot in embedded mode: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/344851/how-do-you-add-a-screenshot-image-to-your-stack-overflow-post

Comment: I have the same problem with multiple larger files! Thanks for asking!

Comment: I wonder if it is something that happens more to ontologists. Maybe adding some tags to OBO and related topics will increase findability of the question.

Comment: @Nicole Maybe try to add what type of file is it or how we can reproduce it. I see that GitHub doesn't render Diffs for large files, not sure how you suggest on 160K lines of file in GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

This is also followed by the Jan. 2023 discussion [#43052: Unable to apply a suggestion to a file conflict to the main branch: This diff has recently been updated.](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/43052)

> It's not about the batch suggestion commit, but about applying commit suggestions to files that has merge conflict to the branch this PR is to be merged into.
>
> This is still a bug, as the commit-suggestion feature should only concern about the branch that holds the changes in this PR, not the branch to merge the changes into.
>
> [image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/44064051/210178073-bcac6ddb-f358-4a53-ab64-1064c2a4d36f.png]

So far, this bug has not yet been addressed.